# What is wrong with this php code to send mail

Tags: javascript, php

I have form in my site and I tried to send messege to email address. I get values from the form and send to a php file by ajax.Then in sendmail.php file I send email with `mail()` function. And `mail()` doesn't send to email, and returns something like this :

```
    <br />
        <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; col.........
```

this is my js code

```
$.ajax({
                            url: "sendmail.php",
                            data: {name:name.val(),email:email.val(),subject:subject.val(),messege:messege.value},
                            type: "POST",
                            success:function(data){
                                console.log(data);  
                            }
                        })
```

and this is in sendmail.php file

```
<?php
$to = "email@mail.com";
$name =$_POST['name'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$subject =$_POST['subject'];
$messege =$_POST['messege'];
if(mail($to,$subject,$messege)) {
        echo 'Email on the way';
    }
?>
```

Who knows why?

Comment: Where is the php code and/or the javascript code?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The class `class='xdebug-error xe-warning'` seems to be an error message of xdebug. Read the full message, you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah. I was afraid of that code))It says that the problem is that I am usin localhost. I am changing the code in server to see what it will return and why isn't the messege sent. Thanks

Comment: In server it works but messege isn't sent.

Answer (score 0):

The description/message content seems to be encoded in different format. Mail() function may sometimes block the data to be send through mail() if there is an error in the content sending.
Please check the content posted in message field.

Comment: I checked the content. in is simple string